# Pointer to struct doesn't work properly?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

```
typedef struct Spheres{
    int PositionX;
    int PositionY;
    int Color;
    int Mass;
    int Radius;
    int SpeedX;
    int SpeedY;
}Sphere;

char readFile(FILE *file,Sphere **totalSphere){
    int positionX,positionY,color,mass,radius,speedX,speedY,amountOfSpheres,i;
    fscanf(file,"%d",&amountOfSpheres);
    *totalSphere=malloc(amountOfSpheres*sizeof(Sphere));
    for (i=0;i<amountOfSpheres;i++){
        fscanf(file,"%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",&positionX,&positionY,&color,&mass,&radius,&speedX,&speedY);
        totalSphere[i]->PositionX=positionX;
        totalSphere[i]->PositionY=positionY;
        totalSphere[i]->Color=color;
        totalSphere[i]->Mass=mass;
        totalSphere[i]->Radius=radius;
        totalSphere[i]->SpeedX=speedX;
        totalSphere[i]->SpeedY=speedY;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",totalSphere[0]->PositionX,totalSphere[0]->PositionY,totalSphere[0]->Color,totalSphere[0]->Mass,totalSphere[0]->Radius,totalSphere[0]->SpeedX,totalSphere[0]->SpeedY);
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",totalSphere[1]->PositionX,totalSphere[1]->PositionY,totalSphere[1]->Color,totalSphere[1]->Mass,totalSphere[1]->Radius,totalSphere[1]->SpeedX,totalSphere[1]->SpeedY);
}


int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    Sphere *totalSphere;
    totalSphere=NULL;
    if ((file=fopen("input.txt","r"))!=NULL){
        if (readFile(file,&totalSphere)){
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",totalSphere[0].PositionX,totalSphere[0].PositionY,totalSphere[0].Color,totalSphere[0].Mass,totalSphere[0].Radius,totalSphere[0].SpeedX,totalSphere[0].SpeedY);
            printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",totalSphere[1].PositionX,totalSphere[1].PositionY,totalSphere[1].Color,totalSphere[1].Mass,totalSphere[1].Radius,totalSphere[1].SpeedX,totalSphere[1].SpeedY);
            fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code and 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJrca.png) is the text file i'm reading from

The problem is that when the function readFile() ends, the values from totalSphere[1] are lost as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMnph.jpg) but the values from totalSphere[0] are ok. Why is this happening?

Comment: Inside `readFile` it should be `(*totalSphere)[i].PositionX = positionX` instead of `totalSphere[i]->PositionX=positionX`. And so on. Everywhere inside `readFile` you are supposed to work with `(*totalSphere)[i].`, not with `totalSphere[i]->`. The latter is completely incorrect.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. main's "totalSphere" is a pointer to structures, and you're accessing it in readFile as if it were a pointer to pointers. Your '->'s need to be '.'s. Turn ALL compiler warnings on and listen to them! And name your variable sanely...you have to variables "totalSphere" that are not only not the same thing, they're not the same type.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker: `main`s `totalSphere` is passed to `readFile` as `&totalSphere` and received in `readFile` as `Sphere **totalSphere`. Nothing wrong here - it should compile perfectly fine. But the code inside `readFile` makes no sense. It appears the author was simply trying to "make it compile" at all costs, not caring about the meaning of the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) honor the right margin on the printed page.  Suggest after a comma, insert a new line and indent the following line(s)

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  it is missing the needed include statements for the needed header files.  Also, the function `main()` is missing two closing brace '}'.  Note: in C, indentation means absolutely nothing (beyond readability)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc)  Always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) use appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators  2) separate code blocks ( for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default ) via a single blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most)  one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions (like `fscanf()`), always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the function: `readFile()`  signature states that it will return a char.  However, it does not return anything.  This cause the compiler to output a warning message.  Then the statement: `if ( readFile( file, &totalSphere ) )`  is expecting something to be returned from `readFile()`, so this code does not work

Comment: this statement: `printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
            totalSphere[1].PositionX,
            totalSphere[1].PositionY,
            totalSphere[1].Color,
            totalSphere[1].Mass,
            totalSphere[1].Radius,
            totalSphere[1].SpeedX,
            totalSphere[1].SpeedY);` will perform undefined behavior if the input file only contains a single instance of `Sphere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got lost in levels of indirection, apparently. The array of `Sphere` objects that you allocated inside `readFile` is supposed to be accessed as `(*totalSphere)[i]`. E.g

```
for (i = 0; i < amountOfSpheres; i++) {
  fscanf(file, "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", &positionX, &positionY, &color, &mass, &radius, &speedX, &speedY);
  (*totalSphere)[i].PositionX = positionX;
  (*totalSphere)[i].PositionY = positionY;
  ...
```

Your original version is incorrect.

The `(*totalSphere)[i]` syntax applies inside `readFile`, since `totalSphere` is `Sphere **` there. In `main` you will access the received array the "regular" way - as `totalSphere[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. corrects the problems listed in the comments to the question
2. pays attention to the parameter types for functions like: `malloc()`
3. properly checks for errors
4. corrects several logic errors
5. cleanly compiles
6. separates the struct definition from the `typedef` for that struct
7. properly cleans up before exiting due to errors
8. passes the allocated memory to `free()` to avoid a memory leak
9. documents why each header file is being included

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fopen(), fclose(), perror(), fscanf(), fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, malloc(), free()

struct Spheres
{
    int PositionX;
    int PositionY;
    int Color;
    int Mass;
    int Radius;
    int SpeedX;
    int SpeedY;
};
typedef struct Spheres Sphere;


// prototypes
size_t readFile( FILE *file, Sphere **totalSphere );


size_t readFile( FILE *file, Sphere **totalSphere )
{
    int positionX;
    int positionY;
    int color;
    int mass;
    int radius;
    int speedX;
    int speedY;
    size_t amountOfSpheres;
    size_t i;

    if( 1 != fscanf( file, "%lu", &amountOfSpheres ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "fscanf for number of spheres failed\n" );
        fclose( file );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    *totalSphere = malloc( amountOfSpheres * sizeof(Sphere) );
    if( !totalSphere )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        fclose( file );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for ( i=0; i<amountOfSpheres; i++ )
    {
        if( 7 != fscanf(file, "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",
            &positionX,
            &positionY,
            &color,
            &mass,
            &radius,
            &speedX,
            &speedY) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "fscanf to read fields of sphere failed\n" );
            fclose( file );
            free( totalSphere );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        (*totalSphere)[i]->PositionX = positionX;
        (*totalSphere)[i]->PositionY = positionY;
        (*totalSphere)[i]->Color     = color;
        (*totalSphere)[i]->Mass      = mass;
        (*totalSphere)[i]->Radius    = radius;
        (*totalSphere)[i]->SpeedX    = speedX;
        (*totalSphere)[i]->SpeedY    = speedY;
    }

    for( size_t j=0; j<amountOfSpheres && j<2; j++ )
    {
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
            (*totalSphere)[j]->PositionX,
            (*totalSphere)[j]->PositionY,
            (*totalSphere)[j]->Color,
            (*totalSphere)[j]->Mass,
            (*totalSphere)[j]->Radius,
            (*totalSphere)[j]->SpeedX,
            (*totalSphere)[j]->SpeedY);
    }

    return amountOfSpheres;
}


int main( void )
{
    FILE *file =NULL;
    Sphere *totalSphere = NULL;

    if ( !(file = fopen("input.txt","r") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    size_t x= readFile( file, &totalSphere );

    for( size_t i=0; i<x && i<2; i++ )
    {
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",
            totalSphere[i].PositionX,
            totalSphere[i].PositionY,
            totalSphere[i].Color,
            totalSphere[i].Mass,
            totalSphere[i].Radius,
            totalSphere[i].SpeedX,
            totalSphere[i].SpeedY);
    }

    fclose( file );
    free( totalSphere );
    return 0;
}
```